# Finding a list of comma separated keywords

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I run my code I cannot retrieve the entry that I am targeting because the keywords that are being run through the query are not the same as the keywords in the database.

Keywords:

```
$keywords = 'spaghetti,macaroni,hamburger';
```

Query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ---- WHERE keywords LIKE '%$keywords%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

I am targeting an entry with these keywords:

```
food, restaurant, hamburger, spaghetti, taco,pie
```

I may be missing something simple here since I've been working for 12 hours straight. However, I've had no luck with anything I've tried to do to work around this issue.

From my point of view the query should be returning the target entry since there are 2 matching keywords.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: That's not how `LIKE` works. You may want to normalize your data so the keywords are in a separate table, linked to the restaurant (or whatever the main records are) by its ID

Comment: You don't need to add `[Solved]` to your question title. *You already did* the appropriate thing and checked the tick mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$like = array();
$keywords = explode(',' , $keywords);
foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
  $like[] = "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
}
$like = implode(' OR ', $like);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE $like ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to break up the keywords and do a separate `LIKE` comparison for each one

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE keywords LIKE '%spaghetti%' OR keywords LIKE '%macaroni%'
-- ...
```

You could do something like this

```
<?php

$keywords = 'spaghetti,macaroni,hamburger';

$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=1";

$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);

if (count($keywords)) {
    $query .= sprintf(
        " AND (%s)",
        implode(' OR ', array_map(function($word){
            return "keywords LIKE '%{$word}%'";
        }, $keywords))
    );
}

echo $query;

// SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=1 AND (keywords LIKE '%spaghetti%' OR keywords LIKE '%macaroni%' OR keywords LIKE '%hamburger%')
```

---

As you can see from the comments, there are better ways to handle this, but I'm assuming that this rudimentary question is looking for a simple answer.

I'm not doing any input sanitization, or adding any other fail safes. Building queries like this is not very reliable and you should continue to learn about PHP/MySQL to avoid common pitfalls in the future.  However, I believe more advanced approaches are a bit out of your reach at the moment. If someone else would like to provide better techniques that they think the OP can grasp, by all means, go for it :)

Comment: Note the query optimizer cannot optimize `keywords LIKE '%spaghetti%' OR keywords LIKE '%macaroni%'` and this will become a sequential scan, using no indexes.  Normalization may be a better solution, as indexes can be used for, e.g. `keywords IN ('macaroni', 'spaghetti')`

Comment: @FrankFarmer - That's a facet of the problem described by the OP.  No answer is ever going to avoid that.

Comment: @dems -- this is one of those "How do I pound nails with a screwdriver?" questions.  While "With the wide end, not the pointy end" is a valid answer, there's a deeper problem that needs to be addressed.  Which is to say, a comma delimited "keywords" field is a symptom of a bad schema.

Comment: That makes sense but the problem that I'm facing is that the keywords are originally coming from a sentence like "Do you want spaghetti, macaroni, or a hamburger for supper?" I'm running that sentence through a simple replace script that results in the keywords spaghetti, macaroni, hamburger. Each sentence that is coming in can be any length so it is difficult to use the OR statement since I don't know for sure how many keywords will be used each time. Does that make sense?

Comment: @PeterMerrill - As hinted at by Frank, you could simplify this radically by changing your data.  Instead of one string with many values, you could *(and probably should)* have many rows instead.  That would probably be a new table of perhaps just two columns `(mytable_id, keyword)`.  Then you could get matching rows simply with `SELECT mytable_id FROM mytable_keywords WHERE keyword IN ('spaghetti','macaroni','hamburger') GROUP BY mytable_id`.  Normalising your data really does make these problems significantly simpler, and normally faster too.

Comment: I added some notes at the bottom here guys; I'm answering in a way I think the OP can digest information right now. Advanced techniques that optimize MySQL's performance for this particular problem seem a bit out-of-reach for the OP right now.

Comment: @PeterMerrill, this solution does handle variable-length keyword input.

Answer (score 2):

Storing multiple values as a CSV inside a column is a common SQL anti-pattern.  It's hard to use and even harder to optimize:

[How to fix the Comma Separated List of Doom](http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may be faster than using multiple `or` clauses

```sql
Select * from mytable
where keywords REGEXP 'spaghetti|macaroni|hamburger'
```

Comment: I've edited your post; you were being caught out be SO using the first tag, `[PHP]`, for the Google Prettify mark-up. This can be changed by a HTML comment, for SQL `<!-- language: lang-sql -->`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `LIKE` with separeted works, you can try this:

```
$keywords = 'spaghetti,macaroni,hamburger';

$arrayWords = explode(',', $keywords);

$like = '';

foreach($arrayWords as $word)
    $like .= empty($like) ? " keywords LIKE '%$word%' " : " OR keywords LIKE '%$word%' ";

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ---- WHERE $like ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ---- WHERE keywords LIKE '%". implode("%' OR keywords LIKE '%", explode(",", $keywords)) ."%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```